# /www contents permission management

Tags: permissions, nautilus, apache2

I was about to install opencart on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I will describe my exact steps-

1. Extracted the **opencart.zip**.
2. `gksudo nautilus`
3. Pasted the opencart folder into `/var/www/html`
4. Now while accessing `localhost/open`, it says **Forbidden Access**.

I checked the permission of `/open`, it was `drwx------ 7 root root 4096 Oct 26 17:26 open`. So basically, it was `700` (I'm not sure though), but I got a sense that permissions needed to be provided to access them.

So I fired terminal, and went on a spree to give all folders a permission of `755` and files - `644`.

Three questions-

1. Was I right till here or not ?
2. If yes, what is the correct way to set permissions ? I did `chmod` for all folders & files individually (with the help of wildcards, obviously). This is actually a very hectic step. There are hundreds of files and folders, so this must not be the right way. What am I missing ?
3. Even last time, I messed up with some permissions of some folders in `/www`, and it rendered me to install Ubuntu. Either there has to be a way to fiddle with /www or should I go with changing default `/www-data` directory ? (No idea how to go ahead with that).

I really want to stick with Linux but this permission thingy is always nagging me.

PS: Right now, if I access `/open`, it opens a blank page.

Thanks, help much appreciated.

Comment: Are you are trying to use Ubuntu as a WebServer? In that case, you should read this https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't create contents of `/var/www` as root user (that's what you did with `gksudo nautilus`). Instead, you should add your user to `www-data` group and put the contents to `/var/www` as a user.

This way, both you and the web server will have access to the data, and you will be able to manage the contents of `/var/www` without having to modify permissions manually.